# Transition Cover Bins not hitting

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog

I am sampling value from data bus, as the intended values are non-consecutive the bins are not hitting for transition coverage. While the bins are hitting standalone without transition.

Example: We want to cover transition of values for address W.

```
A: W | X | W | Z
D: 7 | 0 | 8 | 0
```

```
covergroup cg_ with function sample();
transtion_cp : coverpoint data {
        bins seven_repeat   = (7 [* 2]);
        bins seven_eight  = (7 => 8);
        bins eight_seven  = (8 => 7);
        bins eigth_repeat = (8 [* 2]);
        bins seven = {7};
        bins eight = {8};
  }
function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
  cg_ = new();
endfunction

virtual function void write_axi_bus(svt_axi_transaction axi_tran);
   reg [7:0] var_value;

   if(W == axi_trans.addr && (axi_trans.xact_type == svt_axi_transaction::READ || axi_trans.xact_type == svt_axi_transaction::WRITE)) begin
     var_value = axi_trans.data[0][7:0];    
   end
   cg_.sample(var_value);
endfunction
```

Is anything wrong with the above code, as currently the transition bins are not hitting. But I see the standalone bins are hitting i.e (7,8).
Let me know if I am missing anything in above code.

Comment: You code won't compile because there are too many syntax errors. (bins syntax, function sample argument missing or not even needed) Please be very careful to post the correct code, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @Chinmay, your edits did not fix all syntax errors. Bins `seven` and `eight` are still not correct.  **Please be very careful to post the correct code**

Answer (score 0):

You override the built-in `sample` function using `with sample`, but you do not specify a signal list to pass to it.  When you call `sample` in the `write_axi_bus` function, you pass `var_value`, but `var_value` is not being used for coverage sampling.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 19.3 *Defining the coverage model: covergroup*.

Even if `var_value` were used, it might not have the values you want to sample.  When the `write_axi_bus` function is called, `var_value` is 1st set to `x` (unknown) in the `reg` declaration.  Only when the `if` condition is true do you set `var_value` to a non-x value.

The value of `data` is being used for coverage, which means you need to set it to the expected value when `sample` is called.